# How do I check Grails is installed on a Mac OS?

Tags: macos, grails

I installed Grails on a Mac OS using the gvm.
I did:

```
 gvm install grails version 2.2.1
```

I want to satisfy my paranoia and confirm grails is installed.  Is there something like a `grails -version` equivalent?

Or what is the easiest way to check?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
grails
```

or

```
grails --version
```

or

```
grails help
```

Comment: $:> grails --version is available if the environment variables have been set.  http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/gettingStarted.html 
The quickest proof of installation would be to use: $:> gvm current grails http://gvmtool.net/

Answer (score 2):

grails --version

More information can be found at grails.org

Answer (score 1):

i agree to Fran García. just use gvm.

install gvm with

```
   curl -s get.gvmtool.net | bash
```

then install grails with

```
  gvm install grails 2.3.0
```

then you can check grails with

```
 grails -version
```

Answer (score 1):

just use :

```
$ gvm current grails

Using grails version 2.2.0
```

the cmd will show all the tools installed by gvm.

see the doc for more. http://gvmtool.net/

Answer (score 1):

with following command you can locate where exactly grails is installed.

```
>which grails
>/Users/techtalks/.gvm/grails/2.4.0/bin/grails
```

Answer (score 1):

grails --version 
This should help you get the version of grails

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong the problem is you need to install grails using gvm with the next command:

```
gvm install grails 2.2.1
```

Please note there is no version in the command

Answer (score 0):

By just executing grails, it'll display the grails version anyway. But in order for grails to run or to give you its version with "grails --version" it needs to be in the path. On my mac, I have to open a new terminal in order to read the path after it is installed (or defaulted) by gvm. Maybe this is what's missing and you can't get the version

Answer (score 0):

"grails -version" is the best way to check.

However, use the gvm framework to install/use different version of grails/ groovy/ gradle and other groovy based language.

This way, you could do a "gvm current grails" and see what is the version of grails you are using.

more info can be seen at http://gvmtool.net/

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you have installed several grails, you can use:

`gvm use grails --version`

to change from one version to another.

Answer (score 0):

The command

```
which grails
```

Will tell you if you have a grails distribution in your execution path.

The command

```
find / -iname *grails*
```

Will list all of your data whose name contains the 'grails' string (case insensitive).

Warning: while the former command is pretty quick, the latter could and probably will take a while to run.

### Cheers,

Snoopy